# make lein uberjar without source files

Tags: clojure, leiningen, uberjar

I'm using 'lein uberjar' to make a executable jar file of my project. 
the jar is created correctly and runs as expected.

I just want to know if it is possible to NOT include my source .clj files in the generated .jar, since I'm planning to distribute it, and I don't want my source files available to the public.

I'm using lein 1.7.1

if not possible with lein, would it work if I just manually removed the .clj files from the jar? I did a test and it worked, by I want to be sure that this is safe to do.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `:omit-source true` in lein's `project.clj`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the aot compilation step that is provided?  See [here](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj#L92) for an example.

Also, someone blogged something not too long ago about aot compiling their entire project: http://blog.japila.pl/2012/02/aot-compile-all-namespaces-in-a-clojure-project-aot-all-in-project-clj-leiningen/

In that case, too, you might still have to dig in and remove the .clj files, I'm not sure.  Maybe this is somewhere to start, though.

### Edit 1

I should note that even if you were to use compilation to just distribute the .class files, there are [really good tools](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui) to decompile those classes in a way that users can read (I've used this in the past when the documentation was so poor I had to look elsewhere to see how it worked).

In those cases, you'd be better off finding a way to implement your own code obfuscator, although I know little/nothing about that topic, [here's a start](http://syprog.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/basics-of-data-obfuscation.html?utm_source=Coder+Weekly&utm_campaign=a6889de9de-Coder_Weekly_Issue_17&utm_medium=email).